# R - Specifying a desired row order for the output data.frame of aggregate()

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate

I `aggregate()` the `value` column sums per `site` levels of the R data.frame given below:

```
set.seed(2013)
df <- data.frame(site = sample(c("A","B","C"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 currency = sample(c("USD", "EUR", "GBP", "CNY", "CHF"),10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(10,6,5,6,0.5)),
                 value = sample(seq(1:10)/10,10,replace=FALSE))

df.site.sums <- aggregate(value ~ site, data=df, FUN=sum)
df.site.sums

#  site value
#1    A   0.2
#2    B   0.6
#3    C   4.7
```

However, I would like to be able to specify the row order of the resulting `df.site.sums`. For instance like:

```
reorder <- c("C","B","A")
?special_sort(df, BY=site, ORDER=reorder) # imaginary function
#  site value
#1    C   4.7
#2    B   0.6
#3    A   0.2
```

**How can I do this using base R?** Just to be clear, this is essentially a *data frame row ordering question* where the context is the `aggregate()` function (which may or may not matter).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871464/aggregate-data-frame-while-keeping-original-order-in-a-simple-manner) is relevant but does not directly address my issue, or I am missing the crux of the solution.

---

**UPDATE**

For future reference, I found a solution to ordering a data.frame's rows with respect to a target vector on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-a-data-frames-rows-according-to-a-target-vector-that-specifies-the-desire?rq=1). I guess it can be applied as a post-processing step.

```
df.site.sums[match(reorder,df.site.sums$site),]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a possibility: convert 'site' to a `factor` and specify the order in `levels`.

```
df$site2 <- factor(df$site, levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
aggregate(value ~ site2, data = df, FUN = sum)

#   site2 value
# 1     C   4.7
# 2     B   0.6
# 3     A   0.2
```

**Update** following @Ananda Mahto's comment (thanks!). You can use the 'non-formula' approach of `aggregate`:

```
reorder <- c("C", "B", "A")
with(df, aggregate(x = list(value = value),
                   by = list(site = factor(site, levels = reorder)),
                   FUN = sum))
#   site value
# 1    C   4.7
# 2    B   0.6
# 3    A   0.2
```

Or, converting to factor within the formula interface, and rename the converted site column:

```
df2 <- aggregate(value ~ factor(site, levels = c("C", "B", "A")),
                 data = df, FUN = sum)
df2
names(df2) <- c("site", "value")
df2
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, is there an alternative to specify the order after or during the aggregate()?

Comment: I see that you already have updated your question with an 'after alternative'. I was going to point you to something similar. Right now I don't know about a clean 'during' alternative.

Comment: @Zhubarb, there is also the *non-formula* approach to `aggregate`. `with(df, aggregate(list(value = value), list(site = factor(site, reorder)), FUN=sum))`. Henrik, you can also use `factor` in the formula version, but the resulting column names are funky, so renaming would be required.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks a lot for suggesting the non-formula approach. i add it to the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, yes, I tried using `factor` in the formula version before I posted my first answer, but skipped it due to the funkiness of the names. I haven't tried specifying `x` as a `list` before - useful indeed to be able to set the names of the results column right away. Cheers.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Thanks a lot that solves it! (And thanks Henrik for updating the accepted answer)